# Sample n times with replacement in Julia

Tags: sample, julia

I'm trying to draw n -- say, 10 for simplicity -- samples from an array in Julia. Using the function `wsample`, `ndraws` below gives me what I wanted

```
using Distributions
population = [ 1, 10 ]
weights = [ .4, .6 ]
population_idx = wsample( population, weights, 10 ) # i.e. population indices
ndraws = population[ population_idx ]
```

I'm using `Julia 0.2`. Is there a way to do the same thing **without** the indices? In `R` for instance, we have

```
ndraws <- sample( population, size = 10, replace = TRUE, prob = weights )
```

The [docs](http://juliastats.github.io/Distributions.jl/sample.html) here suggests there is i.e. doing this

```
ndraws = wsample( population, weights, 10 )
```

should give me, err, exactly what I want? Note too, that in the docs, the argument name for number of draws is `n` but looking in the source code of `sample.jl`, it refers to `k`.

Comment: When I run your code, `wsample( population, weights, 10 )` gives the answer you want (values of 1 and 10). When I run `population[ population_idx ]` I get `ERROR: BoundsError()`. Is there some documentation that says `wsample` returns an index? It appears to me to return a sample vector from `population`

Comment: @user3114046 Thanks. Inspection of `methods( wsample )` is what led to the confusion. The whole multiple dispatch business will take a while to sink in. I would've accepted your answer had it not been a comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`wsample(population, weights, n)` returns `n` samples from `population` (not the indexes). This is in the Distributions package.

For example,

```
julia> using Distributions
julia> wsample(["a", "b"], [0.3, 0.7], 10)
10-element Array{ASCIIString,1}:
 "a"
 "b"
 "b"
 "b"
 "b"
 "b"
 "b"
 "b"
 "a"
 "b"
```

If what you want is to draw indexes, you can use `1:k` as the population, for example, `wsample(1:k, weights, n)`.